# How to use api in json with only javascript

Tags: javascript, json, object

I want to fetch data from a API link by using java script. I want to do this in only pure javascript.

Comment: That's the way: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JavaScript function:

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
        callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
}
xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true); 
xmlHttp.send(null);
```